# Android oboe glitch/noise/distortion

Tags: android, c++, audio, oboe

I'm trying to use oboe in my audio/video communication app, and I'm trying the `onAudioReady` round-trip callback as in the oboe guide: https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/main/docs/FullGuide.md

Now I'm frustrating:

1. If the read directly write into the `*audioData`, the sound quality is perfect, i.e.:

```
auto result = recordingStream->read(audioData, numFrames, 0);
```

2. But if I add a buffer between them, there is significant noise/glitch which is very undesirable:

```
auto result = recordingStream->read(buffer, numFrames, 0);
std::copy(buffer, buffer + numFrames, static_cast<int16_t *>(audioData));
```

By inspecting log, this buffering action is done within 1ms, suppose won't hurt?

Both 1 and 2 also use `PCM_I16` audio format, buffer is `int16_t *` with size of `numFrames`.

Hopefully someone can point out what's wrong to cause this? Sorry I'm lack of audio processing and c++ knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out because the channel is stereo, samples per frames are 2, i.e.:

```
auto result = recordingStream->read(buffer, numFrames, 0);
std::copy(buffer, buffer + numFrames * 2, static_cast<int16_t *>(audioData));
```

Comment: can't mark it until 2 days after question created...

Comment: no problem @PhilFreihofner all good